# Deciphering a WordPress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to understand a section of code from this WordPress plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/menu-items-visibility-control/. The first thing I don't understand is the value label of the input: `value="<?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( $item_id, '_menu_item_visibility', true ) ); ?>"` Can someone explain what is going on here? The variable '_menu_item_visibility' is a WP conditional tag entered by the user, and the menu item is hidden unless the tag evaluates to true. I'm also curious what there is no method label for this input.

```html
function option( $item_id, $item, $depth, $args ) { ?>
  <p class="field-visibility description description-wide">
   <label for="edit-menu-item-visibility-<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
    <?php _e('Visibility') ?>:
    <input type="text" class="widefat code" id="edit-menu-item-visibility-<?php echo $item_id ?>" name="menu-item-visibility[<?php echo $item_id; ?>]" value="<?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( $item_id, '_menu_item_visibility', true ) ); ?>" />
   </label>
  </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

wordpress menu item are also post and stored in wp_posts tables with post type `nav_menu_item`, that `_menu_item_visibility` is a post meta save under `wp_postmeta` probably created by the plugin assigned on specific nav menu item, with a value that seem to be either false or true,

the plugin is simply pulling/adding the value of `_menu_item_visibility` post meta from `wp_postmeta` table, then create a condition based on that value